# Unit test gatsby useStaticQuery custom hook

Tags: jestjs, gatsby

I'm trying to test a custom hook which just returns graphql data in gatsby. 
Here is what I have so far but it's giving me an error.

**hook useMyData**

```
    import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

    export default () => {
      const {
        content: { data },
      } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
        query myQuery {
          content {
            data {
              views: 10
            }
          }
        }
      `);
      return data;
    };
```

**Jest test**
    import useMyData from './useMyData';

```
jest.mock('./useMyData', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: () => ({
    useStaticQuery: () => ({
      content: {
        data: {
          test: 'test',
        },
      },
    }),
  }),
}));

test('data is returned', () => {
  const data = useMyData();
  // console.log('data = ', data);
});
```

The above does not run the useStaticQuery. Any know how I would test this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to directly mock the `useStaticQuery` method on `gatsby` module instead of on `./useMyData`. Something along the lines of:

```js
jest.mock('gatsby', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  useStaticQuery: () => ({
    content: {
      data: {
        test: 'test',
      },
    },
  }),
}));
```

Comment: See example on the Gatsby docs https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/unit-testing/#3-useful-mocks-to-complete-your-testing-environment